# Prometheus Adapter Helm Chart Unauthorized

Tags: kubernetes, devops, prometheus, amazon-eks, prometheus-adapter

In our EKS cluster we have prometheus installed using the prometheus-community helm chart. We wanted to start feeding the metrics to an HPA to allow scaling based on CPU, memory and network activity (which is not available in the default metrics server).

After running the helm install command

```
helm install custom-metrics prometheus-community/prometheus-adapter --namespace monitoring --set prometheus.url=http://prometheus-operated.monitoring.svc --set hostNetwork.enabled=true
```

it runs successfully and after a few minutes you can see in Kubectl get apiservices that they have come up and now show as true.

The issue that I'm experiencing is that running any kubectl command such as

```
kubectl get pods -n monitoring
```

the first line always shows

```
E0726 13:18:37.044670   28536 memcache.go:287] couldn't get resource list for custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: Unauthorized
```

followed by the expected output of the get pods command.

When I try to run a kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 -n monitoring I get the follow error message:

```
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

Does anyone know what configuration changes I need to make in order to setup my HPA? I know that custom rules need to be created for the HPA to access them but I plan on setting those up once the adapter is running.

I've tried setting hostNetwork.enabled to true and leaving it at the default as false.

Here is the output of my get SVC command:

```
NAME                                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
alertmanager-operated                            ClusterIP   None             <none>        9093/TCP,9094/TCP,9094/UDP   21d
custom-metrics-prometheus-adapter                ClusterIP   172.20.67.162    <none>        443/TCP                      82m
kube-prometheus-stack-alertmanager               ClusterIP   172.20.196.135   <none>        9093/TCP                     21d
kube-prometheus-stack-grafana                    ClusterIP   172.20.175.12    <none>        80/TCP                       21d
kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics         ClusterIP   172.20.20.63     <none>        8080/TCP                     21d
kube-prometheus-stack-operator                   ClusterIP   172.20.145.105   <none>        443/TCP                      21d
kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus                 ClusterIP   172.20.178.62    <none>        9090/TCP                     21d
kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter   ClusterIP   172.20.217.223   <none>        9100/TCP                     21d
prometheus-operated                              ClusterIP   None             <none>        9090/TCP                     21d
```

Comment: I found there was an error in the logs of the pod:

"Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate ... failed: x509: certificate signed
 by unknown authority"

Answer (score 0):

The custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 is not a standard Kubernetes api. Kubernetes API can be extended with Custom Resources that are fully managed by Kubernetes and available to Kubectl and other tools.

SO Can you try to list all api servers:

`kubectl get apiservice`

all values of should be `True`

You should see something like

```
v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io      kube-system/metrics-server                   True        252d
```

You might want to have a look at whether the metrics server inside of the kube-system is crashing.. something like:

```
kubectl get deployments -n kube-system | grep metrics-server

kubectl describe deployment [metrics deployment name]
```

or

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep metrics-server
```

You can also use [metrics-server](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/metrics-server/metrics-server) as per [AWS documentations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.html)

Comment: Hello Rajhi, Sorry I think there's a misunderstand I do not have metrics-server deplyoed in my cluster. This will not work as it does not have the ability to track network traffic which is what we want to scale off of. This is why I'm trying to connect my HPA to prometheus using the prometheus adapter helm chart. Confirming all APIServices show True.

Comment: I'd be more interested to know why you would need prometheus to run under the hostNetwork if you are running it in kubernetes though. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: Hi Rajhi, I was just trying to play with every flag. I read some similar posts where that solved the issue but unfortunately it did not solve it for me.